# Comparing SQL query results. Is there are performant way to compare them?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some "calculation" logic that relies on the result of a SQL query. If the result, of the query, didn't change then there is no point to run the "calculation". The question is, what is the performant way to compare two query results? I don't need the difference, I just need to know that the result is different.

The most straightforward solution is to compare row to row, is there any better options?
Can I avoid storing the whole previous result?

Comment: Leave it to the DBMS, it is in better position to use cache of earlier query output, or cached query execution plan. It is not going to be worthwhile for you to implement it yourself. DRY!!

Comment: You can hash rows and then hash hashes, finally compare the result hashes